# How to merge session data into a function using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I've asked this subject in another topic but that topic has gone cold and I've directed this topic to the core of the problem.

I've loaded the session library in the previous page and have no issue with the function working in that page.

But it is the next page where I'm having problems. I get the error "Unexpected T_VARIABLE".

I've read the topic on How to solve syntax errors. That topic suggests the line before is usually the problem line, usually by a missing semicolon or bracket.

This is the coding;

```
public function index()
{
$this->load->model('Code_model', 'code_model');
$this->session->email //This is the problem line
$email = $this->session->email
$code = $this->input->post('code');
if ($this->code_model->find_code($email, $code))
{
$this->load->view('username');
}
else
{
$this->load->view('codeincorrect');
}
}
```

I've tried putting a semicolon at the end. And tried adding - userdata('email');
And tried having a separate function containing the problem line with its own brackets. And tried deleting the problem line & the line below. When deleted $email cannot be found.

But nothing works.

Is there somebody who understands how sessions work and how they can be integrated into a function?

Update

This is the Controller coding of the previous page, which works good.

```
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('session');
}

public function index()
{
$this->load->model('Email_model', 'email_model');
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[40]|valid_email|is_unique[tbl_members.email_address]', array(
'required' => 'You have not entered an %s address.', 'min_length' => 'Your %s address must be a minimum of 10 characters.',
'max_length' => 'Your %s address must be a maximum of 40 characters.', 'valid_email' => 'You must enter a valid %s address.',
'is_unique' => 'That %s address already exists in our Database.'));
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // The email address does not exist.
{
$this->load->view('email');
}
else
{
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$random_string = chr(rand(65,90)) . rand(1,9) . chr(rand(65,90)) . rand(1,9) . chr(rand(65,90)) . chr(rand(65,90));
$code = $random_string;
$this->email_model->insert_email($email, $code);
}
}
```

2nd Update - This is the coding for the 2 Controllers and 2 Models

Email Controller

```
class Email extends CI_Controller
{
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->library('session');
}
public function index()
{
$this->load->model('Email_model', 'email_model');
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[40]|valid_email|is_unique[tbl_members.email_address]', array(
'required' => 'You have not entered an %s address.', 'min_length' => 'Your %s address must be a minimum of 10 characters.',
'max_length' => 'Your %s address must be a maximum of 40 characters.', 'valid_email' => 'You must enter a valid %s address.',
'is_unique' => 'That %s address already exists in our Database.'));
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // The email address does not exist.
{
$this->load->view('email');
}
else
{
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$random_string = chr(rand(65,90)) . rand(1,9) . chr(rand(65,90)) . rand(1,9) . chr(rand(65,90)) . chr(rand(65,90));
$code = $random_string;
$this->email_model->insert_email($email, $code);
$this->load->library('email'); // Not sure if this works - testing from localhost
$this->email->from('<?php echo WEBSITE_NAME; ?>', '<?php echo WEBSITE_NAME; ?>'); // Not sure if this works - testing from localhost
$this->email->to('$email'); // Not sure if this works - testing from localhost
$this->email->subject('Code.'); // Not sure if this works - testing from localhost
$this->email->message('Select & Copy this code, then return to the website. - ','$code'); // Not sure if this works - testing from localhost
$this->email->send(); // Not sure if this works - testing from localhost
$this->load->view('code');
}
}
}
```

Email Model

```
class Email_model extends CI_Model
{
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->database();
}
public function insert_email($email, $code)
{
$data = array(
'email_address' => $email,
'pass_word' => $code
);
$this->db->insert('tbl_members', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id();
}
}
```

Code Controller

```
class Code extends CI_Controller
{
public function index()
{
$this->load->model('Code_model', 'code_model');
$this->session->email // Problem line - syntax error, unexpected '$email' (T_VARIABLE)
$email = $this->session->email
$code = $this->input->post('code');
if ($this->code_model->find_code($email, $code))
{
$this->load->view('username');
}
else
{
$this->load->view('codeincorrect');
}
}
}
```

Code Model

```
class Code_model extends CI_Model
{
function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->database();
}
public function find_code($code,$email)
{
$this->db->select('user_id');
$this->db->where('email_address', $email);
$this->db->where('pass_word', $code);
$code = $this->db->get('tbl_members');
if ($code->result())
{
return $this->db->delete('pass_word', $code);
}
}
}
```

Comment: can you post the code that you have created a session

Comment: Just done that.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the sessions library is loaded. You can do this manually by saying:

`$this->load->library('session');`

But if you want it loaded at all times, go to your `autoload.php` file and make sure sessions is added in the `autoload['libraries']` area.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like the buggy. Please check followings.

1. In PHP statements are ended by semi-colon (`;`)
2. `$this->session->email` : returns the value of `email` element from session array and it should be assigned, like the next line as in your code `$email = $this->session->email`.
3. Check whether the `email` is set in the session or not `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());`

Best of luck!

Comment: I dont fully understand your criticism. If I put semi-colon (;) at the end I still get an error. I've inserted print_r($this->session->all_userdata()); after the problem line and commented out the balance of code but get this error - syntax error, unexpected 'print_r' (T_STRING) - Can you answer by rewriting the code the way you think it should be?

Comment: Could you please put the complete controller and model code here? It will help us to find the actual bug.

Comment: If I have 2 text boxes in the code view, 1 for the email address and the other for the code, it should work. Do you know how I can get the email address automatically inserted?

Comment: I spoke too soon. I've created an email text box and the email address automatically inserts. I'm now having an issue with the next view which I'll study and try to resolve.